# localStorage Restored when Page Refreshed?

Tags: javascript, html, web, browser, local-storage

I'm using a Chrome browser and I noticed something weird on one of our sub-domains. if I clear or change local storage, when I refresh the page, the old settings are restored. I have tried to clear at the command line, via Application > Storage > localStorage and Application > storage (hit clear). Regardless I have no idea how to prevent this or get around this issue. Is this an application setting?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code you're currently working with.

Comment: I have to check on a few different computers first to ensure it isn't just mine.

Comment: Another strange thing, when using developer tools if I type in "localStorage" at the command line it shows the settings. If I look at the local storage under Application > Local Storage it doesn't show any entries.

Comment: I figured it out. It was a red herring! The issue was that the code was working as designed. I forgot we were blocking certain GUIDs automatically and that account I used was one of the blocked accounts. Head slapping moment!